# How can I make sure only string and number arguments can be passed?

Tags: javascript

How can I check to see if my arguments are strings or numbers only?

Task 4 - find the smallest number in a list. 
 Allow any number of arguments to be passed to the function. Allow both
String and Number arguments to be passed, but throw an error if any other
 type is passed to the function (e.g., Boolean, Date, etc.). If the list
 is empty (nothing passed to the function), return Number.MIN_VALUE,

```
<script>
 highAndLow =(... numbers) => {

 if(numbers.length<=0){

 return Number.MIN_VALUE;
}
 if (typeof numbers !== 'string' || (isNaN(numbers)===true)){
  throw new Error('Whoops!, Only String and Numbers allowed');
  }else{

 numbers = numbers + '';
  var smallestElement = numbers[0];
  numbers = numbers.split(' ');
   for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (+numbers[i] < +smallestElement) {
      smallestElement = numbers[i];
     }

     }


   }


    return ` ${smallestElement}`;
     };

 console.log(highAndLow('4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 12')); 
   alert(highAndLow('4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 12'));
 </script>
```

Comment: You are supposed to be using multiple arguments, not a single string containing many numbers. You will need to loop over `numbers`, which always will be an array (given you declared it with parameter rest syntax).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the type checking inside the loop. `typeof numbers[i] !== 'string' || (isNaN(numbers[i])===true`